# Troubles pulling up the Date from my object

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I have the following model set up:

```
class ReceiverActions(models.Model):
    ...
    date_paid = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

and I am trying to grab just the date. When I run this in my shell:

```
ReceiverActions.objects.get(identifier="JLWY25B4").date_paid.date
```

I get the appropriate date : `2018-08-12`

but when I try to call it in my views:

```
ra = list(ReceiverActions.objects.filter(
    seller_inventory=ss).values().order_by('id'))
rec_id = [
    x
    for x in ra
    if x['seller_inventory_id'] == inventory['id']][0]
info['paid_date'] = str(rec_id['paid_date.date()'])
```

I am getting undefined.

I have also tried `['paid_date__date']` and `['paid_date.date']`

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Edit: When I call other values such as `red_id['identifier']` it works perfectly.

Comment: What is the value of `ss` here?

Comment: rec_id is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: no it is one dictionary, notice the `[0]` at the end. But anyway, this is defintely not the way to go.

Comment: Well, ideally I am looking for the solution to calling the date. Even though the method of the creation of the dictionary may be questionable. When I call other values it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a small misconception: the dict `rec_id` contains all fields as keys. You need to get the fields value (which is also the dict value) first, and then call methods an it.

And also, you seem to have misspelled the fields name: it should be `date_paid` and not `paid_date`.

So change this line:

```
... = str(rec_id['paid_date.date()'])
```

to this

```
... = str(rec_id['date_paid'].date())
```